# Invalid --log-level value. Unable to initialize logging. Exiting... error while starting Selenium Grid Node

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have problem with Selenium Grid. Then I try to connect to node, i've got an error on node side.+

U run hub by this way:

```
java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

I run node by this way:

```
java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig .\NodeConfig.json
```

NodeConfig.json:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "platform": "WINDOWS",
            "maxInstances": 5,
        "chrome_binary":"chromedriver.exe",
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
            "nodeName": "Local Chrome Node"
        }
      ],
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5,
    "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
    "webdriver.chrome.driver":"<path to chromedriver.exe>"
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5,
    "nodePolling": 5,
    "role": "node",
    "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60,
    "downPollingLimit": 2,
    "debug": false,
    "servlets" : [],
    "withoutServlets": [],
    "custom": {}
}
```

Simplyfied Java code:

```
DriverService service = null;
ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();

opts.addArguments("-incognito");
opts.addArguments("--no-sandbox");      

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), opts);
```

On Java side:
A long stacktrace (I think it's not necessary for this problem)

On Node side:

> java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node
>   -nodeConfig .\NodeConfig.json   15:39:56.377 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision:
>   e82be7d358   15:39:56.513 INFO
>   [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid
>   node on port 5555   2019-06-18 15:39:56.921:INFO::main: Logging
>   initialized @807ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
>   15:39:57.200 INFO [WebDriverServlet.] - Initialising
>   WebDriverServlet   15:39:57.292 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium
>   Server is up and running on port 5555   15:39:57.293 INFO
>   [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up
>   and ready to register to the hub   15:39:57.456 INFO
>   [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread.
>   Will try to register every 5 ms.   15:39:57.955 INFO
>   [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the
>   hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register   15:39:58.106 INFO
>   [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the
>   hub and ready to use   15:40:06.931 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply]
>   - Capabilities are: {     "browserName": "chrome",     "goog:chromeOptions": {
>       "args": [
>         "-incognito",
>         "--no-sandbox"
>       ],
>       "extensions": [
>       ],
>       "binary": "chromedriver.exe"     }   }   15:40:06.933 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory
>   org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory
>   (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)   Starting
>   ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90
>   (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003})
>   on port 21040   Only local connections are allowed.   Please protect
>   ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent
>   access by malicious code.   Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90
>   (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003})
>   on port 9515   Only local connections are allowed.   Please protect
>   ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent
>   access by malicious code.   Invalid --log-level value.   Unable to
>   initialize logging. Exiting...

On Hub side:

> java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
>   15:39:50.884 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version:
>   3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358   15:39:51.000 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub
>   on port 4444   2019-06-18 15:39:51.425:INFO::main: Logging initialized
>   @805ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog   15:39:51.831 INFO
>   [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running   15:39:51.832 INFO
>   [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://%My  IP%:4444/grid/register/   15:39:51.832 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients
>   should connect to http://%My  IP%:4444/wd/hub   15:39:58.105 INFO
>   [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://:5555
>   15:40:06.623 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a
>   new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {args: [-incognito, --no-sandbox], extensions: []}}   15:40:06.632
>   INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test
>   slot {chrome_binary=chromedriver.exe, nodeName=Local Chrome Node,
>   server:CONFIG_UUID=186192e2-e951-4cef-b527-291aa9c0e2f5,
>   seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, webdriver.chrome.driver=/chromedriver.exe, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1,
>   platformName=WINDOWS, version=75, platform=WINDOWS}

So, how to sole this problem and configure logs on node side (I'd like to made it via .json file)

Comment: Update the question more of _Hub_ and _Node_ side trace logs.

Comment: `HubConfig.json` please

Comment: I've not use it.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this error and fixed it. The "Invalid --log-level value" error is caused by using ChromeDriver as Chrome. Selenium runs ChromeDriver, then ChromeDriver runs Chrome. Chrome recognise "--log-level=0", but not ChromeDriver.

What's happening here is that you try to use ChromeDriver to run ChromeDriver. The reason can be specifying ChromeDriver's path as Chrome. E.g. symbolic link chromedriver as chrome, or ChromeOptions.setBinary(".../chromedriver")

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the `NodeConfig.json` and both *Selenium Grid Hub* and *Selenium Grid Hub* logs, there seems to be an issue with the  `--no-sandbox` argument.

---

### Sandbox

The [sandbox](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox_faq.md) library which allows the creation of sandboxed processes that can execute within a very restrictive environment cannot write to disk. Chromium renderers are **sandboxed** processes.

---

### Solution

Some more information about *Selenium* client, *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* version would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However as you are using *Chrome* in *regular* mode (non **headless**), you may drop the *argument* **`--no-sandbox`**.

---

### tl; dr

[Unable to Create Driver Instance for chrome in ubuntu](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qaf-users/ZRUbGWSL7Y8)

Comment: if you don't have an answer to the question, you should obviously refrain from answering.

Comment: I tryed to use headless mode and drop nosandbox - no changes.

Comment: @RiseOfDeath You need to do the reverse. Add `--no-sandbox` only for `headless` case and drop it in general case.